# Raspberry pi inside CRT TV - piggyback off a 220v line on a TV main board?

Tags: power, raspberry-pi, tv

I would like to mount a Raspberry Pi device inside an old CRT TV (yes, I am well aware of CRT safety protocols, I've been restoring them for a few years now).

The Raspberry Pi is powered using 5 volts DC but it can use a considerable amount of power (up to 15 watts) so I would try to avoid piggybacking from a 5V line on the main board. However, the main board of the TV is directly connected to 220V AC (the red circle in the picture)

Therefore, in order to go the easiest route, my plan is to:

1. Use an 220v socket extension cable (would this need to be shielded to prevent interference?)
2. Cut it at one end and solder it either:

- a) on the power plug circled in the picture
- b) somewhere along the power cable coming into the TV (it has a ferrite bead on it so I would likely solder it before the bead to avoid causing interference)

3. Mount the power brick along with the Raspberry Pi inside the TV shell (it's a TV/VCR combo unit so there is plenty of space). I'll also add a tiny fan to keep the case cool.

Would this approach work? Anything I should be careful about?

Here is a crude diagram of what I want to achieve:
[image: wiring diagram]

And here is the 220v plug on the main board:
[image: mainboard]

4. **LATER/OPTIONAL** Solder the composite video cable coming out of the raspberry pi on the back of the composite port (ideally I'd like to solder a switch so I would be able to also use the composite input with an external device, meaning switch between what I plug in and the directly soldered Raspberry pi composite input)